# Should I close stream when reusing FileOutputStream?

Tags: java, fileoutputstream

As stated in the title, should I close stream when reusing a FileOutputStream variable? For example, in the following codes, should I call the `outfile.close()` before I assign it a new file and why?

Thanks:)

```
FileOutputStream outfile = null;
int index = 1;

while (true) {

    // check whether we should create a new file
    boolean createNewFile = shouldCreateNewFile();

    //write to a new file if pattern is identified
    if (createNewFile) {
        /* Should I close the outfile each time I create a new file?
        if (outfile != null) {
            outfile.close();
        }
        */
        outfile = new FileOutputStream(String.valueOf(index++) + ".txt");
    }

    if (outfile != null) {
        outfile.write(getNewFileContent());
    }

    if (shouldEnd()) {
        break;
    }
}

try {
    if (outfile != null) {
        outfile.close();
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.err.println("Something wrong happens...");
}
```

Comment: *"before I assign it a new file"* - Yes, you could leave changes in the buffer, meaning that they might not be saved to the file. You are consuming file handles, which are limited resources in the OS.  You are taking up resources in your JVM. You should always tidy up after yourself. Have a look at [The try-with-resources Statement](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) for a better solution for handling closable resources

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the confusion here revolves around the concept of “re-using” the `FileOutputStream`.  What you are doing is simply re-using an *identifier* (the name `outfile` of your variable) by associating a new value with it.  But this only has syntactic meaning to the Java compiler. The *object* referred to by the name – the `FileOutputStream` – is simply dropped on the floor and will eventually be garbage collected at an unspecified later point in time. It doesn't matter what you do with the variable that once referred to it. Whether you re-assign it another `FileOutputStream`, set it to `null` or let it go out of scope is all the same.

Calling `close` explicitly flushes all buffered data to the file and releases the associated resources. (The garbage collector would release them too but you don't know when this might happen.) Note that `close` may also throw an `IOException` so it really matters that you know the point at which the operation is tried which you only do if you call the function explicitly.

Answer (score 5):

**YES.** Once you are done with one file (stream) you should always close it. So that the resources allocated with the file (stream) will be released to the operating system like file descriptors, buffer etc.

Java Documentation [FileOutputStream.close()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/FileOutputStream.html#close%28%29)

> Closes this file output stream and releases any system resources associated with this stream. This file output stream may no longer be used for writing bytes.

The unclosed file descriptors can even lead to resource leaks in the java program. [Reference](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2014/10/right-way-to-close-inputstream-file-resource-in-java.html)

Answer (score 2):

Even without automatic resource management, or [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) (see below), your code can be made much more readable and reliable:

```
for (int index = 1; shouldCreateNewFile(); ++index) {
  FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream(index + ".txt");
  try {
    outfile.write(getNewFileContent());
  }
  finally {
    outfile.close();
  }
}
```

However, Java 7 introduced a new syntax for closures that is more reliable and informative in the case of errors. Using it, your code would look like this:

```
for (int index = 1; shouldCreateNewFile(); ++index) {
  try (FileOutputStream outfile = new FileOutputStream(index + ".txt")) {
    outfile.write(getNewFileContent());
  }
}
```

The output stream will still be closed, but if there is an exception inside the `try` block, and another while closing the stream, the exception will be suppressed (linked to the main exception), rather than causing the main exception to be discarded like the previous example.

You should always use automatic resource management in Java 7 or above.